# Master boot record shows no active partitions?

Tags: operating-system, boot, bootloader, mbr

I used the following command to check the MBR code in hexadecimal

```
hd -n 512 -v /dev/sda
```

Which displayed this:

[image]

It seems to me, that there is only one partition there. I have dual boot with linux and windows, shouldn't at least there be two?

And, according to this website

https://www.bydavy.com/2012/01/lets-decrypt-a-master-boot-record/

At the adress 1bE, it should be "80" instead of "00", since 80 means it is bootable.

Comment: It is an extended boot record. You will rarely see a partition marked as active. More on Extended boot records can be found here: https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/PartTables2.htm#ebr

Comment: Type `ee` Indicates that this a legacy MBR followed by an EFI header.